# TS-Jest and Typescript: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` on some `node_modules`, which are not transpiled (I guess?). I worked around this by adding these modules to the `transformIgnorePatters` in my Jest config, but this doesn't seem like the way to go. Would someone be able to share a working config for Jest or help me out in any other way?

This is my Jest config:

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "transform": {
      ".(js|ts)": "ts-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(lit-element|lit-html))"
    ],
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(unit.test|unit.spec))\\.(ts|js)$",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^~/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
      "^lodash-es$": "lodash"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "js"
    ],
    "reporters": [
      "default",
      "jest-junit"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
      "text",
      "cobertura"
    ]
  },
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES6",
      "lib": [
        "dom",
        "dom.iterable",
        "esnext"
      ],
      "allowJs": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "strict": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "~/*": ["src/*"]
      },
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "jsx": "react",
      "noEmit": false,
      "outDir": "temp",
      "sourceMap": true,
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have `ts-jest` installed?

Comment: I do have it installed, yes.